# RewriteCond A or (!B and !C)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file on Apache server. I'd like to have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
```

while meaning *"if `http` or request subdomain other than `sub.`(e. g. `www.`), redirect to `https` and without `www.`"*.

- `https://example.com` --> do nothing
- `http://example.com` --> `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com` --> `https://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com` --> `https://example.com`
- `https://sub.example.com` --> do nothing
- `http://sub.example.com` --> `https://sub.example.com`, this will definitely not work with code above
  What's the simplest way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break this into 2 different rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www and https for https://www.example.com or http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# simply add https for rest
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

- Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.
- Change `302` to `301` after testing.

Comment: Hey, I don't want  `www.`, as you can see in examples, `http://www.example.com` should redirect to `https://example.com`, but you are doing it the other way round... One note to R=301: use it only after you've done it all, it's not easy to change it. GTG, try googling it...

Comment: Ok, so breaking into 2 rules needed. I suggested edit, which removes all subdomans, not only www. Look at it.

Comment: I have approved your edit. 2nd rule i.e. `http -> https` is performed for all domains.

Comment: I know that second rule is performed for all domains. But you edited the first one back to removing only `www.`. (What is suggested was 'if any subdomain except `sub.`, remove it.) Although it's not the behaviour I'm asking for in the question, maybe it's better. Thank you for decoding my bad English `:)`